# What is the best way to dump a bit string to a binary file

Tags: c++, serialization

I have some bits stored in a C++ std::string, e.g. `0001010100011` and I need to dump these into a binary file without wasting space. 
I would group every 8 bits together and output a character for each group, for example `000101010` and `00011`.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: How about [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) and its [`to_ulong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) function?

Comment: How can I deal with the padding if the original string's size is not divisible by 8?

Comment: Do you store size information? Do you store other information after to store (do you have alignment requirement)?

Comment: Nope, I do not store any other information, only the bitstring

Comment: If you are grouping by 8-bits, you could write them as a `uint8_t`.  You could have an array of `uint8_t` and then use the bulk/block `read` and `write` methods of the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Supply each 8-bit chunk string `bitchunk` to `unsigned char c = std::stoi(bitchunk, nullptr, 2);` and you'll get a char representation of it in `c`  ready to be stored or manipulated further.

Don't forget to `#include <string>`

Comment: BTW, the character or string representation of bits takes up more space than writing as an integer.  From the OP, "...I need to dump these into a binary file without wasting space."

Comment: char is supposed to be converted into an integer (byte-value) before storing in a binary format. The size of char is always 1 byte.

Comment: Let me clarify, I am saying given "01101101", that would be 8 characters and a null.  One character per byte, for a total of 8 digit characters.  This can be compressed down to 0x6d which fits into one byte.  So the 8 bytes of characters has been compressed down to one byte (8 bits).

Comment: Let me clarify as well, in my highlighted code the ```bitchunk``` is your string holding "01101101" and ```c``` is its char value of 0x6d.